# How to pass a string on page refresh?`

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm having such a problem with this.

Scenario:

When running my action I use an int array to retrieve data based on these ID's. This works perfectly until you reach the view. I manage to retrieve the data fine but whenever I refresh the page, as the array is a complex type it comes through as null in the action. To get around this problem I've converted the array into a string and would like to pass this value to the action on page refresh. But everything I've tried so far doesn't actually submit the value, the parameter definitely gets populated. The parameter which I am trying to pass in is `RPString`

Action:

```
[AuthorizeClientID]
        [LoggingFilter]
        public ActionResult SupplierReportSelection(int ClientID, int[] ReviewPeriodID, string RPString, int? GroupID, int? SupplierID = null, bool? Backbtn = null, int? StatusCategoryID = null) {
            if (TempData["TempReviewPeriod"] != null) {
                ReviewPeriodID = (int[])TempData["TempReviewPeriod"];
            }
            ClaimsBySupplierViewModel SupplierModel = ClaimsBySupplier(ClientID, ReviewPeriodID, SupplierID, GroupID);

            ViewBag.client = client;


            return View("ClaimsBySupplier", SupplierModel);
        }
```

View:

```
 @if (Model.ReportData.Any()) {
            Model.RPString = string.Join(",", Model.inputReviewPeriodIDs);
            Model.RPString = Json.Encode(Model.RPString);          
     //Removed code which isn't needed
        }
```

If JQuery is also a possibility, just let me know.

Comment: How is the array populated during the first succesful request?

Comment: @WiktorZychla The array is populated a drop down which depending on the values the user click on

Comment: Not exactly what I meant. My question is: is the list passed in a query string of a GET request or rather, this is a POSTed list of values? Anyway, have you thought of just storing this in Session so that when it's empty you retrieve it from Session?

Comment: Hmmm, no I hadn't thought about storing it in session, such as a cookie. That's a very good point. I imagine that this will work. I've been busy in the meantime but I'll update and let you know once I get around to fixing it :) Thanks

Comment: @WiktorZychla Thank you very much for the suggestion. The issue has been solved :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has [unload](https://api.jquery.com/unload/) method which is called when user is navigating off the page.

For example, you can do the following:

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "<method>",
        url: "<your url>",
        data: { RPString: <your desired value> }
    })
});
```

Comment: And would I need to pass in the parameter to the URL and then try to retrieve it in the action?

Comment: @AndrewKilburn, in this `unload` callback you can make [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) request to `<host and controller names here>/SupplierReportSelection` and pass your `RPString` parameter. (if I correclty understood your question of course)

Answer (score 0):

```
   [AuthorizeClientID]
        [LoggingFilter]
        public ActionResult SupplierReportSelection(int ClientID, int[] ReviewPeriodID, string RPString, int? GroupID, int? SupplierID = null, bool? Backbtn = null, int? StatusCategoryID = null) {
            if (GroupID == null && SupplierID == null && TempData["TempReviewPeriod"] != null) {
                ReviewPeriodID = (int[])TempData["TempReviewPeriod"];

                //The cookie code is used for the page refresh whenever a user performs a search with multiple ReviewPeriod IDs. This is because you cannot pass the ReviewPeriodID array in the URL.
                Request.Cookies.Remove("RPCookie");
                HttpCookie RPCookie = new HttpCookie("RPCookie");
                for (int i = 0; i < ReviewPeriodID.Length; i++) {
                    if (ReviewPeriodID.Length - 1 != i) {
                        RPCookie.Value += ReviewPeriodID[i] + ",";
                    }
                    else {
                        RPCookie.Value += ReviewPeriodID[i];
                    }
                }
                Response.Cookies.Set(RPCookie);
            }
            else if (GroupID == null && SupplierID == null && TempData["TempReviewPeriod"] == null) {
               ReviewPeriodID = Request.Cookies.Get("RPCookie").Value.Split(',').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray();

            }

            ClaimsBySupplierViewModel SupplierModel = ClaimsBySupplier(ClientID, ReviewPeriodID, SupplierID, GroupID);

            ViewBag.client = client;

            return View("ClaimsBySupplier", SupplierModel);
        }
```

I took a suggestion from Wiktor Zychla up above and used a cookie to store the data. I delete the cookie every time there is data in TempData and recreate the cookie. I then get the cookie if TempData is empty(which it will be on a page refresh) and translate it into my parameter.